# How can I access the public metadata of facebook pages, using my access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

```
{
```

"error": {
      "message": "(#100) Page Public Metadata Access requires either app secret proof or an app token",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "AZGveQoRg2l6tGu5fTMIj3o"
   }
}

Comment: When I try to access the data on public Facebook pages with my access token it shows me that error

Comment: Correct. You need permission to access the data

Comment: It’s one of the features you need to submit your app for approval for first, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access

Comment: thanks for your help